# Approximation by Convolution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $\ f$ be a compactly supported $k$-times differential function on $\mathbb R^n$, and let $\rho$ be a mullifier.  For each $\epsilon > 0$, set:
$$f_\epsilon(x) = \epsilon^{-1} \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(y)\rho \left( \frac{x-y}{\epsilon} \right) \, dy$$
So, we want to show that $\ f_\epsilon \rightarrow f$ in $\mathcal C^k(\mathbb R^n)$.  I think that I understand the proof, but wish that someone can make it cleaner.  Specifically, please review the part labelled $(**)$.  I am not sure if I am bounding the variables correctly.

> Set $z = \frac{x-y}{\epsilon}$, we can rewrite the above as:
>   $$f_\epsilon(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x - \epsilon z) \rho(z) \, dz$$
>   Since $\rho$ is bounded in its support and equals zero otherwise, $M = \int |\rho(z)| \, dz$ exists.  Then, since $\ f$ is compactly supported, it is uniformly continuous over $\mathbb R^n$.  For each given $\delta$, there exists an $\epsilon$ such that:
>   $$\|x - y\| \le \epsilon \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \big| \, f(x - y) - f(x) \, \big| < \frac{\delta}{2M} \ \ \ \ \ (**)$$
>   It follows that whenever $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, we have:
>   \begin{align}
> \big| \, f_\epsilon(x) - f(x) \, \big| \ \ & = \ \ \left| \, \int_{\mathbb R^n} [ \, f(x - \epsilon z) - f(x) \, ] \rho(z) \, dz \, \right| \\
> & \le \ \ \int_{\mathbb R^n} \big| \, f(x - \epsilon z) - f(x) \, \big| |\rho(z)| \, dz \\
> & \le \ \ \left( \, \int_{\mathbb R^n} |\rho(z)| \, dz \, \right) \cdot \frac{\delta}{2M} \ \ = \ \ \delta/2
> \end{align}
>   Thus, whenever $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, $\|f_\epsilon - f\| < \delta$.  This proves that $\ f_\epsilon \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $\mathbb R^n$.  Similarly, $\partial^\alpha f_e \rightarrow \partial^\alpha f$ uniformly on $\mathbb R^n$ for each $\alpha$ with $| \alpha | \le k$.

Comment: $f_\epsilon = \rho_\epsilon \ast f$ so that $\partial^\alpha f_\epsilon = \rho_\epsilon \ast \partial^\alpha f$ and the proof for $\|f-f_\epsilon\|_\infty \to 0$ works the same for showing $\|\partial^\alpha f-\partial^\alpha f_\epsilon\|_\infty \to 0$.  Also the convergence of the derivative and $f_\epsilon(0)$ implies the convergence of $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo on $(**)$. What it should say is that "For each given $\delta$, there exists $\epsilon$ such that
$$\Vert y\Vert\leq\epsilon\Rightarrow\Vert f(x-y)-f(x)\Vert\leq\frac{\delta}{2M}$$
This is simply the definition of uniform continuity.

Also, there's a detail which is not addressed on the calculations: $\rho$ is compactly supported, so there is $k$ such that $\rho(z)=0$ whenever $\Vert z\Vert>k$. Thus all integrals can be restricted to $\Vert z\Vert<k$. If $k\leq 1$, then the calculations are correct (since in this case $\Vert z\epsilon\Vert\leq \epsilon$. If $k>1$, we have to do the same calculations but with $\epsilon/k$ in place of $\epsilon$ (i.e., prove that $|\Vert f_{\epsilon/k}(x)-f(x)|\leq\delta/2$).